# REST/XMLHttpRequest with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, xmlhttprequest

can you help me with solving the problem and getting data by REST API:

Info: GET User // This endpoint returns information about a specific user.
HTTP REQUEST - https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/:id_or_username

Page that is valid: https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/Luqpa

I am using the following script:

```
function createRequest() {
          var result = null;

            result = new XMLHttpRequest();

          return result;
    }


    var req = createRequest(); // defined above
        // Create the callback:
        req.onreadystatechange = function() {
          if (req.readyState != 4) return; // Not there yet
          if (req.status != 200) {
            // Handle request failure here...
            return;
          }
          // Request successful, read the response
          var resp = req.responseText;
          // ... and use it as needed by your app.
    }

    url = "https://www.codewars.com/api/v1/users/Luqpa";

    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.send();

    var status = req.status;
    var status_text = req.statusText;

    var xmlDocument = req.responseXML;
    console.log(xmlDocument);
    console.log(status);
    console.log(status_text);

    console.log (req);
```

All responses are either null or 0

I have tried various possiblities and read other tutorials and have not found solution. Please, suggest me how to solve it and get the info from the page ....

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine to me.I think you are facing Cross Origin Resource sharing problem.

Did you test it after appending below flag to your browser?

```
--disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files --allow-file-access
```

These flag will allow your program to access the resource across domain.

Just remember these flags are only for **development** purpose not meant for **production** environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your req.responseXML is null, but req.responseText is not. 
You have a JSON formatted answer. 
Try to change responseXML to responseText and see if that helps you.